# Custom pin (annotation) animation on map

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, animation, mapkit

I want a custom pin annotation on a map. I have the animation code but I can't seem to implement it as an annotation on a map.

My animation code for the circle is:

```
func animation() {
    // The circle in its smallest size.
    let circlePath1 = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 200,y: 150), radius: CGFloat(3), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true)

    // The circle in its largest size.
    let circlePath2 = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 200,y: 150), radius: CGFloat(60), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true)

    // Configure the layer.
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = green.CGColor
    shapeLayer.fillColor = green.CGColor
    // This is the path that's visible when there'd be no animation.
    shapeLayer.path = circlePath1.CGPath
    self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

    // Animate the path.
    let pathAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
    pathAnimation.fromValue = circlePath1.CGPath
    pathAnimation.toValue = circlePath2.CGPath

    // Animate the alpha value.
    let alphaAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
    alphaAnimation.fromValue = 1
    alphaAnimation.toValue = 0

    // We want both animations to run together perfectly, so we
    // put them into an animation group.
    let group = CAAnimationGroup()
    group.animations = [pathAnimation, alphaAnimation]
    group.duration = 2.4
    group.repeatCount = FLT_MAX

    // Add the animation to the layer.
    shapeLayer.addAnimation(group, forKey:"sonar")

}
```

Here is some of the code for the map:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    let identifier = "MyPin"

    if annotation.isKindOfClass(MKUserLocation) {
        return nil
    }

    // Reuse the annotation if possible
    var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(identifier)

    if annotationView == nil {

        annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "pin")

        // I have an image here, but instead I want my custom animation
        annotationView!.image = UIImage(named: "watch")

    } else {
        annotationView!.annotation = annotation
    }

    return annotationView
}
```

I currently have a custom image called `watch` for the pin annotation, but what I want is this animation. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here some inspiration:

https://github.com/TransitApp/SVPulsingAnnotationView

Similar but different. But many techniques are the same I think.

Comment: Hey that was very useful and it did get me further. The only problem is that when I scroll around my map or leave the app and come back, my animation freezes (stops). I don't understand the code from the link above enough to try and apply some of his ideas onto my app since I'm ok, but not great with Objective-C. Any thoughts on how to solve this?